# Converter data em mês por extenso

Tags: r

Tenho uma tabela no r com um coluna com os meses em formato numérico

```
data = c("01", "03", "03", "04", "05", "10", "12"))
```

Gostaria de converter nas abreviações dos meses. Achei como colocar as abreviações em inglês mas não consigo colocá-las em português.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar a função `month` do pacote `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

data = c("01", "03", "03", "04", "05", "10", "12")

month(as.numeric(data), 
      label = TRUE, 
      locale = "pt_BR")
## [1] Jan Mar Mar Abr Mai Out Dez
## 12 Levels: Jan < Fev < Mar < Abr < Mai < Jun < Jul < Ago < Set < Out < ... < Dez
```

Como `data` é um vetor de caracteres, precisei transformá-lo para um vetor numérico primeiro.

A opção `locale = "pt_BR"` serve, justamente, para que as abreviações dos meses sejam criadas em português do Brasil.

Comment: Nota: em Portugal agora os meses escrevem-se com inicial minúscula e `locale = "pt_BR"` usa essa convenção. Não há diferença se for `locale = "pt_PT"`. O sistema é Ubuntu 19.10/R 3.6.2